# Accessing the first elements in a list of Lists [F#]

Tags: recursion, f#, sublist

I'm currently interested in F# as it is different to everything I have used before. I need to access the first element of each list contained within a large list.
    If I assume that the main list contains 'x' amount of lists that themselves contain 5 elements, what would be the easiest way to access each of the first elements.

let listOfLists = [ [1;2;3;4;5]; [6;7;8;9;10]; [11;12;13;14;15] ]

My desired output would be a new list containing [1;6;11]

Currently I have

```
let rec firstElements list  =
    match list with
    | list[head::tail] -> 
        match head with
        | [head::tail] -> 1st @ head then firstElements tail
```

To then expand on that, how would I then get all of the second elements? Would it be best to create new lists without the first elements (by removing them using a similar function) and then reusing this same function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use map to extract the head element of each child list:

```
let firstElements li =
  match li with [] -> None | h::_ -> Some h

let myfirstElements = List.map firstElements listOfLists
```

I'm using Ocaml's speak with little lookup on F# so this may be inaccurate, but the idea applies.

**EDIT**: You can also use `List.head` which makes it more concise and will return a `int list` instead of `int option list`. However, it throws an exception if you hits an empty list. Most of the time, I'd avoid using `List.head` or `List.tail` in this case.

Comment: This returns a list of `int option`s, not a list of `int`s.

Comment: In any case I think that's better because it forces you to handle the empty list case, instead of getting an error from `List.head`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a quick question regarding this, how would you apply it to lists with an unknown length? Say I wanted to extract all the second elements. Would I first write a function to remove the first elements then reapply this function? Then I could continue this until all elements are extracted and in separate lists?

Comment: In addition to `List.head`, there's `List.tryHead`, which is *exactly* identical to the `firstElements` function in this answer. As a general rule in F#, any function that could fail (e.g., `List.head` would fail on an empty list) will have a version with `try` in the name that returns an option. So `List.head` returns an `int` but could throw an exception; `List.tryHead` returns an `int option` and will never throw an exception. If you *know* that the lists you have are never empty, then `List.head` is easier to use. If they *might* be empty, then `List.tryHead` makes you handle both cases.

Comment: @CodeGuy before you resort to recursion, see if you can achieve it with pattern matching. For a second element, you could match with `_::m::_` case and you'll either get a `Some m` or `None`.

Comment: Just use collect to return the list of int.

Answer (score 5):

The easisest way to access the first element in a list is `List.head`. As you have a list of lists, you just need to `List.map` this function:

```
let listOfLists = [ [1;2;3;4;5]; [6;7;8;9;10]; [11;12;13;14;15] ]

listOfLists 
|> List.map List.head
//val it : int list = [1; 6; 11]
```

Now if you need to access other elements, you can use `List.item` or just index into your list with `xs.[1]`. But please keep in mind, that for large lists this will be inefficient and if you want fast look up use an array.

```
listOfLists
|> List.map (List.item 1)
//val it : int list = [2; 7; 12]
```

With indexing:

```
listOfLists
|> List.map (fun x -> x.[1])
```